# What inequalities for convex sets are known since the work of Scott and Awyong?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, convex-geometry, geometric-inequalities

In 2000, Paul R. Scott and Poh Way Awyong published the paper [*Inequalities for Convex Sets*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1508B1F92FD04E83ADF21E05308C88EE?doi=10.1.1.390.7188&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which nicely collates the known results relating various natural geometric functionals (diameter, area, etc.) on convex planar sets.

Given that some of the inequalities in the paper cite results published just a few years prior (or in [one case](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1999.12005035), 18 years later!), it seems that the state of knowledge about these inequalities is still evolving, so I would expect some new results to have arisen in the two decades since its original publication.

**Which new results are known relating geometric functionals on planar convex sets?** In particular, I would love to find an equivalent version of this paper with up-to-date information on the current state of knowledge, existing conjectures, etc., or a reliably-updated webpage tracking the same.

Two related extensions of the original paper I would be interested to see:

- An extension of the table on relationships between pairs of functionals giving results for additional measurements, of which there are many possible choices (though perhaps none so natural as the ones in the original paper).
- An analogous collection of results for convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^3$, though of course the number of natural functionals grows substantially and obtaining exact results is likely much harder.

Comment: Now posted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381395/what-inequalities-for-convex-sets-are-known-since-the-work-of-scott-and-awyong).

Comment: There are a gazillion sharp inequalities relating natural geometric functionals on the space of convex sets. I have no access to the paper of Scott and Awyong, but it is highly unlikely they touched upon more than a small fraction of the most important inequalities.

Comment: It's also worth quoting the Mathscinet review of this paper: "The authors compile a list of known inequalities for convex sets in the Euclidean plane that involve two or three of the following quantities associated with the convex set: the area, the perimeter, the diameter, the width, the inradius, and the circumradius. They also describe a technique for conjecturing new inequalities of this type and they state seven conjectures. The paper contains no new theorems and no proofs."

Comment: I did find a link to the paper: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1508B1F92FD04E83ADF21E05308C88EE?doi=10.1.1.390.7188&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @Deane: Thanks for the updated link, didn't realize the previous one had 404'd - replaced!

Answer (score 2):

A few assorted papers I've come across since posting this question:

---

[Deylon et al. (2021)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.05749.pdf) fully solve the $(A,d,r)$ triple. They make reference to Cifre and Salinas (2002) (doesn't appear to be available online), which shows that $A$ is lower bounded by the area of shapes of the following form:

[image]
(Note however that this minimization problem shouldn't be too hard; I believe it amounts to a bit of messy calculus on a two-variable optimization problem for each $(d,r)$ tuple.)

For the upper bound of $A$, they find that one of two families of shapes attain their proven bounds depending on the ratio $d/r$: either "spherical slices" that look like

[image]

or a peculiar smoothed nonagon shape shown below:

[image]

---

[Brandenberg and Merino (2014)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6808.pdf) fully characterizes the realizable $(d,w,r,R)$ tuples with three new inequalities, introducing some novel extremal shapes like the "sailing boat" and the sliced Releaux triangle:

[image]

---

Deylon et al. describe the aforementioned paper of Cifre and Salinas as containing "several interesting inequalities for $(p, d, r)$ and $(p, R, w)$", but lacking access to the paper I can't say anything more.

---

In [*Chords halving the area of a planar convex set*](http://tizian.cs.uni-bonn.de/publications/gkms-chapc-05.pdf), Grüne et al. consider the functionals $h_A$ and $H_A$, respectively the minimum and maximum-length chords bisecting the area of a convex body, and prove several inequalities (not all of them tight) relating these functionals to each of $A,p,d,w,r,R$.